# Download File does not do anything

Tags: 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

1 Saved download file (ISO) to USB stick but it doesn't do anything other than want to creat a DVD.

2 Saved the file to hard drive but it cannot be read by windows.

Is there a way to download the working program directly to the USB Stick?

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to install Ubuntu on Windows. In that case, you may not even need a USB stick. Download the ISO file and don't do anything with it. Make sure it has the *exact same file name*. Then, download [Wubi](http://mirror.as29550.net/releases.ubuntu.com//quantal/wubi.exe) and run the downloaded file. Follow all instructions and reboot when requested. Every time you start your computer, you will be asked to choose between Ubuntu and Windows®.

You can also download [Unetbootin](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Funetbootin.sourceforge.net%2F&ei=PuWKUIaYKI270AGIj4DgDQ&usg=AFQjCNFG2iJy14ueI6PKA0HBkn1cP-KoBg&sig2=8Q-YI8sGYkdLcZ4z3taRtQ) and run that, pointing it to the ISO file you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

yes first install lili or LinuxLive USB Creator.
then you create live or boot-able pen drive.
Now you can run the OS directly to the USB stick.